# HTML template with flexbox

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I would like to succeed in doing this using flexbox, I have already tried something but without success.
You have to put the title, the price and the input in flex-direction column, right?

**Css**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.details {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.quantity {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quantity button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Mon Panier</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="details">
      <img src="https://aaaestrie.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/livres.jpg" width="150">
      <span>title</span>
      <span>39 €</span>
      <div class="quantity">
        <button class="btn-minus">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
        <button class="btn-plus">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**expected template**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: You need one flexbox for the row, and one for the middle section(title, price, color, input)

Comment: direction is how the parent dispatch the children, not how children dispatch themselves. With that structure, grid is what you need to dispatch children into columns and rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you are trying to get? It's not quite you showed in the image but it's near.  
Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.details {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.quantity {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quantity button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}
.details span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
} 
.details span:nth-child(3) {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
.container {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.details img {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.inc-dec {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;  
/*   transform: translate(-100%,-100%); */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Mon Panier</h2>
  <div>
    <hr>
    <div class="details">
      <img src="https://aaaestrie.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/livres.jpg" width="150">
      <span>title</span>
      <span>39 €</span>
      <div class="quantity">
        <div class="inc-dec">
        <button class="btn-minus">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
        <button class="btn-plus">+</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, there are 2 price in glued to the image and the other to the right of the image the input below price as in the picture.

Comment: So do you want me to make that whole card? And btw Don't forget to accept my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you added "Angular" tag to your question so I assume you are using Angular.
if that's the case I highly recommend to use the `npm` package `angular-flex-layout` so you don't need to write so much CSS.

import the `angular-flex-layout` module in your app and watch the magic :)

```
<div>
  <h2>Mon Panier</h2>
  <div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <img src="https://aaaestrie.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/livres.jpg" width="150">
       
      // magic starts here
      <div 
           fxLayout="column" 
           fxLayoutAlign="center center" 
           fxLayoutGap=".5rem"
      > 
          
          <span>title</span>
          <span>39 €</span>
          <div class="inc-dec">
            <button class="btn-minus">-</button>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
            <button class="btn-plus">+</button>
          </div>

     </div> // magic ends here

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```